# Accessing wifi router in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to access wifi router in PHP if yes then how?

- I want to get wifi router information in PHP connected to my localhost/Server.
- I want to access wifi router in PHP and get all information about the router
- I am working on a geofencing project in PHP
- I searched out different PHP network functions and also take a look on socket programming in PHP but don't get a clear way forward

Code to get the IP address of host (but I want information about a router):

```
$myIP = gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`));
    echo $myIP;dd();

<?php
```

Simple Code Example:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
    socket_bind($socket,'0.0.0.0',150);

socket_getsockname($socket, $IP, $PORT);

print $IP.":".$PORT."\n";

?>
```

Comment: If your router has a web interface you can login and access it via curl.

Answer (score 2):

Most routers nowadays have an SSDP service. Basically, you sent a small packet to a broadcast address and a lot of devices will respond to it. Your router will be one of them.

My router exposes itself as an "urn:dslforum-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1" and SSDP can filter for you for only that device. This quick and dirty piece of code works for me:

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, getprotobyname('udp'));
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, true);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec'=> 1, 'usec'=>'0'));
//socket_set_option($socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, "xxxx"); //only if you have multiple network cards
$data = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\n".
        "HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\n".
        "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\n".
        "MX: 1\n".
        "ST: urn:dslforum-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1\n\n";
socket_sendto($socket, $data, strlen($data), 0, "239.255.255.250", "1900");
socket_recvfrom($socket, $mess, 1024, 0, $ip, $port);
echo $mess;
echo $ip;
socket_close($socket);
```

So now you have the ip address of your router. Using UPnP you can now query your router. My router offers a lot of information through UPnP, some of which are:

- My WAN ip address
- My wifi SSID name, wifi channel, speeds
- Information about connected devices like host names, ip addresses etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step would be finding the IP of your router. For this you'd look at the routing table and look for the "default gateway."

One way to get the routing table is running a shell command for example with `shell_exec`. The command to run depends on the o.s.

- Mac: `netstat -rn`
- Linux: `ip route`
- Windows: `route print`